# HTML select form - how to trigger "dynamically generated option"

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a HTML form along with a script, which *automatically triggers*  the default "option" (option values hard-coded).

I also have a stand-alone script, which creates the choices of "options" dynamically, based on a specific column values in MySQL.

Problem: When selecting from the drop-down list from the dynamically generated list, it does not "trigger" anything (nor manual, nor automatic, manual would be just fine in this case)

The form which auto-triggers the default "option":

```
<form>
    <select name="fruit" onchange="showFruit(this.value)">
        <option>Choice:</option>    
        <option value="1">Yellow Fruit</option>
        <option value="2">Red Fruit</option>
    </select>
</form>

<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var el = document.getElementsByName('fruit')[0];
        el.value = 1; //Set default value
        el.onchange(); //trigger onchange event
    }

    function showFruit(val) {
        alert(val);
    }
</script>
```

And the code which generates the dynamically created "options" list from a specific MySQL column:

```
<? $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', '*', '*', '*');   
 $sql="SELECT DISTINCT(fruit_name) AS fruit_name FROM fruit ORDER BY fruit_name ASC"; 
 $result  = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  

 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){  
 $select= '<select name="select">';
 while($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  
      $select.='<option value="'.$rs['id'].'">'.$rs['fruit_name'].'</option>';
  }
}
$select.='</select>';
echo $select;
```

How can I have the onload function to attach to the dynamically generated "options" list? I don´t need any hard-coded "options" at all. Just the dynamically generated one. And when I select from the list, I would like to get a response/reaction of any sorts.

Comment: Your `select` in the php  part has the name `select`, but your `select` tag in the html part has the name `fruit`. Your javascript listens only to the name `fruit`. Maybe thats your problem?

Comment: Thank you, twain, for your response. That does not seem to be the issue, the issue appears to be related to the fact that the "dynamically" generated options list (which works) does not get associated with the "onload" function.. reworded my whole problem statement, hopefully helps to explain better...

Answer (score 0):

I would probably keep them separated for clarity of purpose and include your template file into your logic file that does the work of formatting the data for the page. By gating the select menu behind a conditional you can make sure it only renders when you have data to put in it.

I formatted this in a particular way, that you don't need to follow but it is fairly good practice to pick a consistent style and stick to it throughout. I also updated your usage of the mysqli class to the object oriented approach. Be aware that in this case you aren't vulnerable to sql injection while using `Mysqli->query`, but if you are planning on taking user input you should study prepared statements to prevent [sql injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).

practically I use the `<?= ?>` operator in the template file this is a shorthand for `<?php echo '';?>`, use of `<?` as your php file opener is discouraged `<?php` is standard.

> [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) also allows for short open tag `<?` (which is discouraged since it is only available if enabled using the short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option).

When mixing PHP and HTML usually its more clear (opinion!) to use the alternative if and loop syntax where possible (the `<?php if () : ?> <?php endif; ?>` rather than `<?php if () { ?> <?php } ?>`) but both work

#### Logic File

```
<?php  
  // page.php 
  $display = false;

  $mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, SCHEMA);
  $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(fruit_name) AS fruit_name FROM fruit ORDER BY fruit_color ASC"; 
  $result = mysqli->query($sql);

  // not sure this is necessary in this particular case, but 
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      $display = true;

      $select = []
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          $select[] = "<option value=\"{$row['id']}\">{$row['fruit_name']}</option>";
      }
  }

  include 'htmlfile.php';
?>
```

#### Template File

```
<!-- htmlfile.php -->
<form>
    <?php if ($display) : ?>
        <select name="select">
            <?= implode('', $select) ?>
        </select>
    <?php endif; ?>
</form>

<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var el = document.getElementsByName('fruit')[0];
        el.value = 1; //Set default value
        el.onchange(); //trigger onchange event
    }

    function showFruit(val) {
        alert(val);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, D Lowther! I tried it out and somehow get the following error message:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE) in /***dir***/page.php on line 16...

Any ideas what might possibly cause that error for the "while" statement?

Comment: Also, I am guessing I would need a semicolon after the   $select = [ ] in the logic file?